# Is it possible to map an existing buffer to a new file?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, posix, mmap

The idea is relatively simple, but I see some complications for implementations, so I'm wondering if it's even possible right now.

- An example of what I'd like to do is to generate some data in a
  buffer, *then* map the contents of this buffer to a file.  Instead of
  having the memory space virtually populated with the contents of the
  file, I'd like the contents of the original buffer to be transferred
  to the system cache (which should be a zero-copy operation) and
  dirtied immediately (which would flush the data out to disk
  eventually).

Of course the complication I mentioned is that the buffer should be deallocated and unmapped (since the data is now under the responsibility of the system cache), and I don't know how to do that either.

The important aspects are that:

- The program can control when the file is <s>created</s> linked.
- The program isn't required to anticipate the size of the file nor does it have to remap it as the dataset grows.  Instead it can realloc the initial buffer (using an efficient memory allocator for this) until it is satisfied (it knows for sure that the dataset won't grow anymore) before finally mapping it to the file.
- The data remains accessible through the *same* virtual memory address even *after* being mapped to the file, still *without* a single intra-memory copy.

One assumption is that:

- We can use an arbitrary memory allocator (or memory management scheme in general) that can manage dynamic buffers more efficiently than mmap/mremap can for the memory space it manages, because the latter must deal with the filesystem to grow/shrink the file, which would always be slower.

So, (1) are these requirements too constrained?  (2) Is this assumption correct?

PS:  I had to arbitrarily pick the tags for this question, but I'm also interested in hearing how BSDs and Windows would do this.  Of course if the POSIX API allows to do this already, that would be great.

**Update:**  I call a buffer a space of private memory (private to the process/task in any OS with normal VMM) allocated in primary memory. The high-level goal involves generating a dataset of an arbitrary size using another input (in my case the network), then once it's generated, make it accessible for long periods of time (to the network and to the process itself), saving it to disk in the process.

- If I keep the datasets in private memory and write them out normally, they'll just be swapped when the OS needs the space, which is a bit stupid since they're already on disk.
- If I map another region then I have to copy the contents of the buffer to that region (which resides in the system cache), which, again, is a tad stupid since I won't use that buffer after that.

The alternative that I see is to write or use a full-blown userland cache reading and writing to the disk itself to ensure that (a) pages don't get uselessly swapped out and (b) the process doesn't hold too much memory for itself, which is never possible to do optimally anyway (better let the kernel do its job), and which is simply not a road I think is worth going down (too complex for less gains).

**Update:** Requirements 2 and 3 are non-issues considering Nominal Animal's answer.  Of course this implies that the assumption is incorrect, as he proved is almost the case (overhead is minimal).  I also relaxed requirement 1, `O_TMPFILE` is indeed perfect for this.

**Update:** [A recent article on LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/591723/) mentions, somewhere in the middle: *"That could possibly be done with a special write operation that would not actually cause I/O, or with a system call that would transfer a physical page into the page cache"*. That suggests that indeed, there is currently (April 2014) no way to do this at least with Linux (and likely other operating systems), much less with a standard API. The article is about PostgreSQL, but the issue in question is identical, except perhaps for the specific requirements to this question, which aren't defined in the article.

Comment: What do you call `buffer`? What is your high-level goal?

Comment: See 'Update' for an answer to your questions and a bit of clarification.  I'd also like some help on how to best go about this since I obviously did something wrong here (maybe just a small comment).  Thanks.

Comment: Create the target file, using `posix_fallocate()` to tell the OS how large the file will be; this reduces file fragmentation. Use `posix_fadvise(, POSIX_FADV_RANDOM)` to disable readahead for that file. Use low-level POSIX I/O (`write()`) to write the contents of your buffer to the file. Discard your buffer, reopen the file `O_RDONLY`, and map the file using `mmap(NULL,length,PROT_READ,MAP_SHARED|MAP_NORESERVE,fd,0)`. In Linux, this will reuse the pages used to write to the file, and not use swap. If there is enough free RAM, the data is only copied once (memory to memory). Need an example?

Comment: @Nominal Animal Thanks for your comment, sorry for the delay. I think your solution is close to my second bullet point in my "update", minus your optimizations regarding filesystem allocation and proper swap usage. I would have loved avoiding that copy; I believe it's possible in theory, but I don't know if any API allows it. Thanks for offering to write an example, I think it's pretty intuitive, but feel free to do so for other people. For the lack of a better alternative, I might accept your answer after all.

Comment: How about you use a memory map for the initial buffer? Create a "hidden" file (it has to be on the target filesystem), then map it using `mmap(NULL,length,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED|MAP_NORESERVE,fd,0)`. The `MAP_NORESERVE` means the file will be used instead of swap. You can remap it (using `ftruncate()` to grow or shrink the backing file) via `mremap()`, similar to `realloc()`. When you wish to "save" it into a file, just rename the file, or hard-link it; both require the new name to be on the same filesystem (but not in the same directory).

Comment: Yep, this is what I thought of initially - I tried to express it in my "assumption" bullet point.  Technically it'll do, but I started from there thinking "Why should we interact with the filesystem at this point when we know for sure that the dataset will continue to grow?  Why not wait until we know exactly what size the generated dataset is?".  To reiterate, the assumption is that `mremap` is slower and "less appropriate" than `realloc`.

Comment: In Linux, if your allocation exceeds about 128k by default, the C library uses `mmap()` and `mremap()` anyway, so "`mremap()` is slower than `realloc()`" can only be valid for data smaller than that. I personally would *not* assume `mremap()` is slower than `realloc()`, except for very small allocations.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it would be slower when backed by a file or device. I think the behavior you're describing only involves anonymous mappings AFAICT. However, I'm thinking (out loud) that explicitly locking the pages of a file-backed mapping in memory until the dataset is fully generated might at least avoid some useless writes. Depending on the filesystem, if delayed allocation is available, the overhead might then be minimal. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user2266481: Why not test it?

Comment: Kernel would need to copy the data in any case if it didn't start at 4K boundary and the length of data were dividable by 4K because then kernel cannot simply remap those pages in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a satisfactory answer to the question; is is more of a continuation of the comment chain.

Here is a test program one can use to measure the overhead of using a file-backed memory map, instead of an anonymous memory map.

Note that the `work()` function listed just fills in the memory map with random data. To be more realistic, it should simulate at least the access patterns expected from real-world usage.

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Xorshift random number generator.
*/

static uint32_t xorshift_state[4] = {
    123456789U,
    362436069U,
    521288629U,
    88675123U
};

static int xorshift_setseed(const void *const data, const size_t len)
{
    uint32_t state[4] = { 0 };

    if (len < 1)
        return ENOENT;
    else
    if (len < sizeof state)
        memcpy(state, data, len);
    else
        memcpy(state, data, sizeof state);

    if (state[0] || state[1] || state[2] || state[3]) {
        xorshift_state[0] = state[0];
        xorshift_state[1] = state[1];
        xorshift_state[2] = state[2];
        xorshift_state[3] = state[3];
        return 0;
    }

    return EINVAL;
}

static uint32_t xorshift_u32(void)
{
    const uint32_t temp = xorshift_state[0] ^ (xorshift_state[0] << 11U);
    xorshift_state[0] = xorshift_state[1];
    xorshift_state[1] = xorshift_state[2];
    xorshift_state[2] = xorshift_state[3];
    return xorshift_state[3] ^= (temp >> 8U) ^ temp ^ (xorshift_state[3] >> 19U);
}

/* Wallclock timing functions.
*/

static struct timespec wallclock_started;

static void wallclock_start(void)
{
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &wallclock_started);
}

static double wallclock_stop(void)
{
    struct timespec wallclock_stopped;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &wallclock_stopped);
    return difftime(wallclock_stopped.tv_sec, wallclock_started.tv_sec)
         + (double)(wallclock_stopped.tv_nsec - wallclock_started.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
}

/* Accessor function. This needs to read/modify/write the mapping,
 * simulating the actual work done onto the mapping.
*/
static void work(void *const area, size_t const length)
{
    uint32_t *const data = (uint32_t *)area;
    size_t          size = length / sizeof data[0];
    size_t          i;

    /* Add xorshift data. */
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        data[i] += xorshift_u32();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long   page, size, delta, maxsize, steps;
    int    fd, result;
    void  *map, *old;
    char   dummy;
    double seconds;

    page = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);

    if (argc < 5 || argc > 6 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s MAPFILE SIZE DELTA MAXSIZE [ SEEDSTRING ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "Where:\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "       MAPFILE     backing file, '-' for none\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "       SIZE        initial map size\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "       DELTA       map size change\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "       MAXSIZE     final size of the map\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "       SEEDSTRING  seeds the Xorshift PRNG\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Note: sizes must be page aligned, each page being %ld bytes.\n", (long)page);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (argc >= 6) {
        if (xorshift_setseed(argv[5], strlen(argv[5]))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid seed string for the Xorshift generator.\n", argv[5]);
            return 1;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Xorshift initialized with { %lu, %lu, %lu, %lu }.\n",
                            (unsigned long)xorshift_state[0],
                            (unsigned long)xorshift_state[1],
                            (unsigned long)xorshift_state[2],
                            (unsigned long)xorshift_state[3]);
            fflush(stderr);
        }
    }

    if (sscanf(argv[2], " %ld %c", &size, &dummy) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid map size.\n", argv[2]);
        return 1;
    } else
    if (size < page || size % page) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Map size must be a multiple of page size (%ld).\n", argv[2], page);
        return 1;
    }

    if (sscanf(argv[3], " %ld %c", &delta, &dummy) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid map size change.\n", argv[2]);
        return 1;
    } else
    if (delta % page) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Map size change must be a multiple of page size (%ld).\n", argv[3], page);
        return 1;
    }

    if (delta) {
        if (sscanf(argv[4], " %ld %c", &maxsize, &dummy) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid final map size.\n", argv[3]);
            return 1;
        } else
        if (maxsize < page || maxsize % page) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Final map size must be a multiple of page size (%ld).\n", argv[4], page);
            return 1;
        }

        steps = (maxsize - size) / delta;
        if (steps < 0L)
            steps = -steps;

    } else {
        maxsize = size;
        steps = 0L;
    }

    /* Time measurement includes the file open etc. overheads.
    */
    wallclock_start();

    if (strlen(argv[1]) < 1 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-"))
        fd = -1;
    else {
        do {
            fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600);
        } while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
        if (fd == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }

        do {
            result = ftruncate(fd, (off_t)size);
        } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
        if (result == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
            unlink(argv[1]);
            do {
                result = close(fd);
            } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
            return 1;
        }

        result = posix_fadvise(fd, 0, size, POSIX_FADV_RANDOM);
    }

    /* Initial mapping. */
    if (fd == -1)
        map = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, fd, 0);
    else
        map = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_NORESERVE, fd, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory map failed: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        if (fd != -1) {
            unlink(argv[1]);
            do {
                result = close(fd);
            } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
        }
        return 1;
    }
    result = posix_madvise(map, size, POSIX_MADV_RANDOM);

    work(map, size);

    while (steps-->0L) {

        if (fd != -1) {
            do {
                result = ftruncate(fd, (off_t)(size + delta));
            } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
            if (result == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot grow file: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
                unlink(argv[1]);
                do {
                    result = close(fd);
                } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
                return 1;
            }
            result = posix_fadvise(fd, 0, size, POSIX_FADV_RANDOM);
        }

        old = map;
        map = mremap(map, size, size + delta, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
        if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot remap memory map: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            munmap(old, size);
            if (fd != -1) {
                unlink(argv[1]);
                do {
                    result = close(fd);
                } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
            }
            return 1;
        }
        size += delta;
        result = posix_madvise(map, size, POSIX_MADV_RANDOM);

        work(map, size);
    }

    /* Timing does not include file renaming.
    */
    seconds = wallclock_stop();

    munmap(map, size);
    if (fd != -1) {
        unlink(argv[1]);
        do {
            result = close(fd);
        } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    }

    printf("%.9f seconds elapsed.\n", seconds);
    return 0;
}
```

If you save the above as `bench.c`, you can compile it using

```
gcc -W -Wall -O3 bench.c -lrt -o bench
```

Run it without parameters to see the usage.

On my machine, on ext4 filesystem, running tests

```
./bench - 4096 4096 4096000
./bench testfile 4096 4096 4096000
```

yields 1.307 seconds wall clock time for the anonymous memory map, and 1.343 seconds for the file-backed memory map, meaning the file backed mapping is about 2.75% slower.

This test starts with one page memory map, then enlarges it by one page a thousand times. For tests like `4096000 4096 8192000` the difference is even smaller. The time measured does include constructing the initial file (and using `posix_fallocate()` to allocate the blocks on disk for the file).

Running the test on tmpfs, on ext4 over swRAID0, and on ext4 over swRAID1, on the same machine, does not seem to affect the results; all differences are lost in the noise.

While I would prefer to test this on multiple machines and kernel versions before making any sweeping statements, I do know something about how the kernel manages these memory maps. Therefore, I shall make the following claim, based on above and my own experience:

Using a file-backed memory map will not cause a significant slowdown compared to an anonymous memory map, or even compared to `malloc()`/`realloc()`/`free()`. I expect the difference to be under 5% in all real-world use cases, and at most 1% for typical real-world use cases; less, if the resizes are rare compared to how often the map is accessed.

To user2266481 the above means it should be acceptable to just create a temporary file on the target filesystem, to hold the memory map. (Note that it is possible to create the temporary file without allowing anyone access to it, mode 0, as access mode is only checked when opening the file.) When the contents are in final form, `ftruncate()` and `msync()` the contents, then hard-link the final file to the temporary file using `link()`. Finally, unlink the temporary file and close the temporary file descriptor, and the task should be completed with near-optimal efficiency.

Comment: Actually this might be a very satisfactory answer for my needs.  I can reproduce your results, but I'm using a virtual machine on a host and hypervisor that I don't know the inner workings of.  I will test as soon as possible on a native machine and report back some numbers as well.  I tried to test for the worst case by msync'ing with MS_ASYNC after each work unit, which made things [*consistently faster*](http://pastebin.com/t2ZV9VVQ) (and confused me).  Definitely interesting.

Comment: @user2266481: Aside from certain performance regressions in specific kernel versions fixed very soom in later versions, I would be very surprised to find any contrary results to my post above. It's a pretty common workload, and therefore the Linux kernel will try to perform it well. As to `MS_ASYNC`: the code tells the kernel the data will be accessed randomly, to simulate *"worst case"*. Change to `POSIX_[FM]ADV_NORMAL` or `POSIX_[FM]ADV_SEQUENTIAL`, and perhaps preload the next work unit using `POSIX_MADV_WILLNEED`, for better performance for your specific workload.

Comment: @tne: Thanks for the bounty :) In case you (or others) wonder about it, the "anonymous inode" (`O_TMPFILE`) support in future Linux kernels (3.11 and later) does not change the situation. It does provide a method of making the mapped file inaccessible (by others) during dataset building, but that's it. On the other hand, in Linux, you can use file leases to delay other processes from accessing the mapped file (for up to `/proc/sys/fs/lease-break-time` seconds); long enough to for example destroy the data via `ftruncate()` if so desired. Let me know if you want an example of this.

Comment: Yes, `O_TMPFILE` with `linkat` is great though, I've been wanting exactly this for a long time (these notes look funny now). The name is a bit unfortunate. Didn't know about `lease-break-time` until now, am I correct though that you're suggesting this as an alternative for systems that don't yet support `O_TMPFILE` [A]? (Ignoring forked children.)

Comment: [B] About worst-case testing, I actually wanted to make sure the code didn't incur useless writes to the system during processing of the whole workload. The system periodically flushes these pages, `MS_ASYNC` was really meant to force it to do so a lot. It's really apparent with `MS_SYNC`, obviously (+20s on the same test) but irrelevant. It's hard to test because it doesn't influence the process itself that much (actually makes it go faster for some reason), but does impact on the system and thus other instances of the program (at least that's what I want to determine).

Comment: @tne: [A]: Exactly! Use `fcntl(fd,F_SETFD,FD_CLOEXEC)` to avoid any `fork()` issues (closing a duplicate descriptor should not release the lease AFAIK, unlike advisory locks). [B]: With `MAP_SHARED`, the kernel does writeback only if there is enough memory pressure, otherwise the pages are in page cache (shared with file access). That kind of memory pressure will slow down operation anyway, as read-only files cached are preferred over read-write maps. I expect *no* automatic writeback (syncing) during normal operation, i.e. when not RAM-starved.

Comment: That's great to hear. I was all ready to `mlock` or `*_WILLNEED` things up in primary memory, but I guess it might not even be necessary then (except if the work unit is really long running, but then it's not clear that the system shouldn't need to reclaim some pages for other things in the mean time anyway). Still a bit stunned as to why a file-backed mapping with `MS_ASYNC` is consistently faster than an anonymous mapping, but I guess that's another question. Also impressed that filesystem allocation is that fast in normal conditions. Well, well, accepted ;). Thanks a lot!